# R shiny scroll wellPanel

Tags: r, shiny

Is it possible to scroll a wellPanel or column?

I have a simple ui scheme here.

```
shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        wellPanel(),
        wellPanel()

        ),
        mainPanel(
          fluidRow(
            column(3,
             wellPanel()
            )
          )
        )
    )
  )
)
```

I would like to make some of those wellPanels (with forms inside) scrollable.

I tried adding this piece of code seen below under 'sidebarPanel(', but that made my whole sidebarpanel to scroll. I am looking to make a 'wellPanel' or a 'column' scrollable.

```
tags$head(tags$style(
  type = 'text/css',
  'form-group { max-height: 600px; overflow-y: auto; }')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Thanks to Carlos Sanchez, here is the answer:

```
wellPanel(id = "tPanel",style = "overflow-y:scroll; max-height: 600px",
other-stuff..)
```

Comment: I found that this created strange behavior.  I wanted the column to scroll so that the rest of the page would remain visible while the user scrolled through a lengthy list of `radioButton` widgets.  I found that the labels and choice names scrolled, but the radio buttons remained fixed.  Did you have any similar issues?

Comment: I haven't checked it recently, but it worked for me back then. If you have complex code, it might be that some ui elements are in the wrong place.

Comment: It might be the function I am using to make the widgets.  You can see it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34079518/r-shiny-panel-scroll-bar-moves-text-but-not-radio-buttons

Comment: Oskar Forsmo figured it out.  I was using inline radio widgets, with set `position:relative` in CSS.  I just had to add the same to the `style` of the panel and then your solution worked perfectly.

Comment: I am looking to be able to scroll left-right within a figRow or tabpanel from shiny dashboard.  I tried replacing "overflow-y" with "overflow-x" and setting max-width instead of height but it did not work.  Ideas welcome