# r shiny panel scroll bar moves text but not radio buttons

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to have a `sidebarPanel` with a large number of **inline** radioButton widgets that control the behavior of some output in the `mainPanel`.  I'd like to be able to scroll through the `radioButton` widgets without scrolling down on the `mainPanel`.  However, the ways I have tried to do it so far result in either the entire page scrolling, or the `sidebarPanel` scrolling but leaving the radio buttons in place (which looks super weird).  Note that this does not happen when I leave the `radioButton` widgets vertical (`inline = FALSE`).  The code below allows you to change whether the `radioButton` widgets are displayed with `inline` turned on or off.

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      id = "tPanel",style = "overflow-y:scroll; max-height: 600px",
      uiOutput("RadioGrid2")),
    mainPanel(uiOutput("InlineChooser")) )
))
```

**server.R**

```
    library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  #Data
  RowNames = LETTERS
  ColumnNames = c("1","2","3","4","5")

  #Define a function that creates rows of radio buttons
  RadioRow = function(label, opts){
    choices = as.list(1:length(opts))
    names(choices) = opts
    radioButtons(paste0("Row",label),label=label,choices=choices,selected=1, inline = input$InRows)}

  #Define a function that creates the radio grid
  RadioGrid = function(RowNames, ColumnNames){lapply(X = RowNames, FUN = RadioRow, opts = ColumnNames)}

  #define a reactive object to hold the radio grid
  WidgetGrid2 = reactive({RadioGrid(RowNames, ColumnNames)})

  #create the output object to display the grid
  output$RadioGrid2 = renderUI({tagList(WidgetGrid2())})

  #create output object to select whether to do inline or not
  output$InlineChooser = renderUI(radioButtons("InRows", label = "Put in rows?", choices = list("yes" = TRUE, "no" = FALSE), selected = TRUE))
})
```

How can I set it so that the scroll bar works when `inline` is turned on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you display your radio-buttons in rows they have the CSS `postion:relative` so setting `postion:relative` to the container div helps to position them correctly (instead of floating). Try this:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      id = "tPanel",style = "overflow-y:scroll; max-height: 600px; position:relative;",
      uiOutput("RadioGrid2")),
    mainPanel(uiOutput("InlineChooser")) )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  #Data
  RowNames = LETTERS
  ColumnNames = c("1","2","3","4","5")

  #Define a function that creates rows of radio buttons
  RadioRow = function(label, opts){
    choices = as.list(1:length(opts))
    names(choices) = opts
    radioButtons(paste0("Row",label),label=label,choices=choices,selected=1, inline = input$InRows)}

  #Define a function that creates the radio grid
  RadioGrid = function(RowNames, ColumnNames){lapply(X = RowNames, FUN = RadioRow, opts = ColumnNames)}

  #define a reactive object to hold the radio grid
  WidgetGrid2 = reactive({RadioGrid(RowNames, ColumnNames)})

  #create the output object to display the grid
  output$RadioGrid2 = renderUI({tagList(WidgetGrid2())})

  #create output object to select whether to do inline or not
  output$InlineChooser = renderUI(radioButtons("InRows", label = "Put in rows?", choices = list("yes" = TRUE, "no" = FALSE), selected = TRUE))
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks.  Would you say that, in general, whenever I am using inline radio buttons, I should set `style="position:relative"` in the panel that contains them?

Comment: Good question, It seems that you need to do that (unless you change the CSS for the radio-buttons) although I'm not sure if this is because I haven't quite grasped how to use the `radioButtons` function properly.

Comment: For anyone interested in this topic, there is a git repository with several variations on the idea located at https://github.com/debarros/WidgetList