# What to do when the sidebar is too long in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

In the following toy example I have a lot of sliders in the sidebar. For the last ones I cannot see the plot in right anymore. Is there any solution to this problem that doesn't involve deleting sliders?

```
# 01-kmeans-app

palette(c("#E41A1C", "#377EB8", "#4DAF4A", "#984EA3",
  "#FF7F00", "#FFFF33", "#A65628", "#F781BF", "#999999"))

library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel('Iris k-means clustering'),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', names(iris)),
    selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', names(iris)),
    selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', names(iris)),
    selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', names(iris)),
    selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', names(iris)),
    selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', names(iris)),
    selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', names(iris)),
    selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', names(iris)),
    selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', names(iris)),
    selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', names(iris)),
    selectInput('ycol', 'Y Variable', names(iris),
      selected = names(iris)[[2]]),
    numericInput('clusters', 'Cluster count', 3,
      min = 1, max = 9)
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput('plot1')
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  selectedData <- reactive({
    iris[, c(input$xcol, input$ycol)]
  })

  clusters <- reactive({
    kmeans(selectedData(), input$clusters)
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    par(mar = c(5.1, 4.1, 0, 1))
    plot(selectedData(),
         col = clusters()$cluster,
         pch = 20, cex = 3)
    points(clusters()$centers, pch = 4, cex = 4, lwd = 4)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I don't see any sliders in your code? do you mean `selectInput`s? When I run your code I see the full graph and a long list of inputs in the sidebar. Is the sidebar overlapping your graph?

Comment: Yes, I thought that a slider is what `selectInput` are called. If you can still see it, then just add more of those until you cannot see the plot. My question is what to do when you get to that point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you could try to add a scroll down bar to the sidePanel

thanks to [R shiny scroll wellPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29290433/r-shiny-scroll-wellpanel)

```
# 01-kmeans-app

palette(c("#E41A1C", "#377EB8", "#4DAF4A", "#984EA3",
          "#FF7F00", "#FFFF33", "#A65628", "#F781BF", "#999999"))

library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    headerPanel('Iris k-means clustering'),
    sidebarPanel(id = "tPanel",style = "overflow-y:scroll; max-height: 600px; position:relative;",
        selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', names(iris)),
        selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', names(iris)),
        selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', names(iris)),
        selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', names(iris)),
        selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', names(iris)),
        selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', names(iris)),
        selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', names(iris)),
        selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', names(iris)),
        selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', names(iris)),
        selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', names(iris)),
        selectInput('ycol', 'Y Variable', names(iris),
                    selected = names(iris)[[2]]),
        numericInput('clusters', 'Cluster count', 3,
                     min = 1, max = 9)
    ),
    mainPanel(
        plotOutput('plot1')
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    selectedData <- reactive({
        iris[, c(input$xcol, input$ycol)]
    })

    clusters <- reactive({
        kmeans(selectedData(), input$clusters)
    })

    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
        par(mar = c(5.1, 4.1, 0, 1))
        plot(selectedData(),
             col = clusters()$cluster,
             pch = 20, cex = 3)
        points(clusters()$centers, pch = 4, cex = 4, lwd = 4)
    })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```