# Huge plot gets cropped in shiny, would scrollbar be helpful?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm trying to plot a pie chart using R's shiny app but the problem is that the legends are more than hundred and hence the chart itself gets cropped.

Have a look at the screenshot here

[image]

I tried the height and width parameters but it wasn't of any use. Is there a way to enable scrolling so that I can see the entire chart including legends without any of these being cropped?

Comment: Pie charts can be useful in very rare cases, pie chart with over 100 labels never.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But for any ggplot in general, is there a way to enable scrolling?

Comment: Maybe see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30765338), [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/JfGnQqAv4RU), and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29290433)? Also, this post looks like "opinion based", "is it better to do X", and might get closed.

Comment: Thanks, I had already tried the last two links, the second one is not yet answered and the third one wouldn't work for ggplot. I'll try the first link and leave an update